# $(element).find("#custom-table") not returning anything in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, angularjs

I'm trying to add a scroll event to the tbody of the table, But when I try to find the tbody of the table using the $(element).find("#custom-table"); it returns nothing.

This is the angularjs directive which I have defined

```
  app.directive("customTable", [
    function () {
      return {
        scope: {
          provider: "@",
          onDelete: "&",
          onEdit: "&",
          onDblClick: "&",
          bindingKey: "@",
          cardsView: "=",
          groupByFromAbove: "=",
          groupByItemFromAbove: "=",
        },
        controller: TableCtrl,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          const content = element.children();

          scope.element = element;
          scope.bindScrollEvent = function () {
           

            $(element)
              .find("#custom-table")
              .on("wheel", function (e) {

                if (e.originalEvent !== undefined) e = e.originalEvent;
                if (scope.processing) {
                  return;
                }
                $(element).scrollTop(e.deltaY);
                const contentElement = $(element).find(
                  ".ngscroll-content-container"
                );
                const containerElement = $(element).find("tbody");
                const scrolledHeight = -(
                  parseInt(
                    $(element)
                      .find("div.ngscroll-content-container")
                      .css("margin-top"),
                    10
                  ) + (e.wheelDeltaY || e.wheelDelta)
                );
                const contentHeight = contentElement.height();
                const containerHeight = containerElement.height();
                const maxScrollableHeight = contentHeight - containerHeight;
                // console.log(contentHeight, containerHeight, maxScrollableHeight, scrolledHeight);
                // load more data when scroll will reach 60%
                console.log("Scrolling", scrolledHeight);
                if (scrolledHeight >= maxScrollableHeight * 0.6) {
                  scope.processing = true;
                  // console.log('loading more at @ ', scrolledHeight, maxScrollableHeight);
                  scope.config = { silent: true };
                  scope.loadMore();
                }
                // console.log(contentHeight, containerHeight, maxScrollableHeight, scrolledHeight);
              });
          };

          scope.bindScrollEvent();
          $(document).on("click", (e) => {
            $("td").removeClass("focus");
          });
        },
        templateUrl: "components/table/table.html",
      };
    },
  ]);
```

& this is the `table.html` file

```
<div
  ng-if="dataService.getFiltersForUI().length > 0"
  class="row funnelByFilter scrollbar"
>
  <div class="col-md-12 overflow funnel-bg">
    <span style="color: #2a2f4d">Filters:</span> &nbsp;
    <div
      class="list-inline-item"
      ng-repeat="funnelby in dataService.getFiltersForUI() track by funnelby.fieldName"
    >
      <span
        class="badge badge-pill ripple-outline-primary badge-outline-primary py-2"
        >{{funnelby.value}}
        <a class="ml-1"
          ><i
            class="fa fa-times-circle"
            aria-hidden="true"
            ng-click="removeFunnelItem(funnelby)"
          ></i></a
      ></span>
    </div>
    <a class="ml-1" ng-click="onRemoveAllFilters();"
      ><span class="badge badge-pill ripple-primary badge-primary py-2"
        >Clear All Filter</span
      ></a
    >
  </div>
</div>
<div class="funnelByFilter_all">
  <table class="xyz-table tableBodyScroll sort" ng-if="!groupByActive">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th
          ng-repeat="column in columns | onlyEnabledItems"
          ng-click="sortBy(column, $event)"
        >
          <div class="d-flex">
            <p class="pull-left">{{column.value}}</p>
            <div class="pull-right">
              <span
                ng-if="orderBy[0] && (orderBy[0] === column.key || orderBy[0] === '-' + column.key)"
              >
                <button class="btn-icon">
                  <i
                    class="fa"
                    ng-class="orderBy[0].toString() === column.key ? 'fa-sort-amount-up' : 'fa-sort-amount-down'"
                  ></i>
                </button>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <div class="dropdown-opt-btn mt-2" ng-init="avoidDropdownClose()">
          <ul>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <button
                data-toggle="dropdown"
                class="btn dropdown-toggle dropdown_btn btn-dropdown-sm btn-opt-more"
                type="button"
                aria-haspopup="true"
                aria-expanded="false"
              >
                <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu btn-edit-menu checkbox-menu allow-focus">
                <li
                  class="dropdown-item"
                  ng-repeat="(colIndex, col) in columns"
                >
                  <div
                    class="checkbox_box_withText d-flex align-items-center justify-content-start"
                  >
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      ng-model="col.enabled"
                      ng-change="changeColumn(colIndex, col)"
                      id="checkbox-{{$index}}"
                      hidden
                    />
                    <label
                      for="checkbox-{{$index}}"
                      class="d-flex align-items-center"
                    >
                      <label class="custom_checkbox" for="checkbox-{{$index}}">
                        <i
                          class="fa fa-check text-white"
                          aria-hidden="true"
                        ></i>
                      </label>
                      &nbsp;<span class="f-s-14">{{col.value}}</span>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-scrollbar scrollbar-x="false" scrollbar-config="{show: false}" id="custom-table">
      <tr ng-repeat="(indexRow, row) in dataService.getData()">
        <td
          ng-repeat="(indexColumn, column) in columns | onlyEnabledItems"
          ng-click="onColumnClick($event, indexColumn, 'td', column)"
          customcontext="context1"
          ng-dblclick="dblClick(row.id)"
          ng-right-click="getRow($event, {{indexColumn}}, {{row}})"
        >
          <div class="groupTitle" ng-if="indexColumn === 0">
            <div class="check-row">
              <div class="check check-orange-bg">
                <div class="checkbox_box">
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    id="demo1-{{indexRow}}"
                    hidden
                    ng-click="onCheck($event, row)"
                  />
                  <label class="custom_checkbox" for="demo1-{{indexRow}}">
                    <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <span ng-click="onColumnClick($event, indexColumn, 'span',  column)"
              >{{row[column.key]}}</span
            >
          </div>
          <div
            ng-if="indexColumn != 0 && column.key === 'picture'"
            class="user_image"
          >
            <i
              for="user_image"
              class="fa fa-camera edit-customer-camera"
              aria-hidden="true"
            ></i>
            <img
              ng-src="ws/rest/com.axelor.meta.db.MetaFile/{{row.picture.id}}/content/download?image=true&v=0&parentModel=com.axelor.apps.base.db.Partner"
              alt=""
              class="img-fluid"
            />
            <div ng-if="!row.picture" class="icon_initials">L</div>
          </div>
          <span ng-if="indexColumn != 0 && column.key != 'picture'"
            >{{row[column.key]}}</span
          >
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <div id="context1" class="dropdown-content">
      <div>
        <a ng-click="funnelBy()"
          ><i class="fa fa-filter text-white"></i> &nbsp;Funnel By
          <p style="color: #fff; font-size: 0.625rem; padding-left: 1.563rem">
            {{currentCellValue}}
          </p></a
        >
      </div>
      <a ng-click="edit()"
        ><i class="fa fa-pencil text-white"></i> &nbsp;Edit</a
      >
      <a ng-click="removeElements();"
        ><i class="fa fa-trash text-white"></i> &nbsp;Delete</a
      >
    </div>
  </table>

  <group-by-view
    data="data"
    on-edit="on-edit"
    ng-if="groupByActive"
    groupbyitem="groupByItem"
    cards-view="cardsView"
    columns="columns"
    provider="provider"
  ></group-by-view>
</div>
```

I have added an id of `custom-table` to the tbody of the table but when I use .find inside the angularjs directive, It returns nothing.

Comment: What element do you expect `element` to be ?

Comment: As IDs must be unique, it should be possible to change `$(anything).find("#id")` to `$("#id")`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen The directive

Comment: @freedomn-m Yeah I'm not sure why it is not working